# How to build index of words from PostScript generated by DVIPS?

Tags: dvi, dvips, postscript, latex-2.09

The background story is, I'm building Common Lisp the Language from its [publicly released source](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/cltl2.html), the source is in LaTeX 2.09 and was build by "Textures, an implementation of TeX by Blue Sky Research for the Apple
Macintosh computer."

Now, I have successfully made the LaTeX 209 fmt to build all the content from the available content (thankfully, TeX itself haven't changed much since 90's), and planning to restore the code commented out that is for building index. Since the original font metrics was unknown, it is impossible to reproduce a copy with the exact same pagination.

I have even successfully build the [Index of functions](https://ldbeth.sdf.org/cltl2.html) which the aid of some custom tools I made.

Now what troubles me is, there was an index of terms like such:

```
Field 1
43-man squamish 544
aardvarks 671, 890
Ada 17, 111, 231--232, 526
Algol 43-44
amber, meaning of 525
anagrams 556
Andrews, Julie 226
antimony 281, 285
APL 29, 31, 34, 308, 309, 314, 924
apples 178
```

But unlike the index of functions, I don't think they have used any markup in the LaTeX source to generate this index.
My guess is they used a tool to scan the PostScript generated by DVIPS (or maybe DVI) to build the above index. I have no knowledge of the existence of such type of tools since it was likely part of legacy preparatory software. If you know enough PostScript or DVI, please help.

Comment: What makes you think this was done by automation? Usually indexing is done by hand.

Comment: Even if you know any scriptable/command line PDF search tool would help. At least I don’t want to completely go through the 1000 pages to find the page numbers.

Comment: There is https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/457778/how-can-i-search-a-string-in-a-pdf-file-and-find-the-physical-page-number-of-ea/457780#457780 which gives the page number from the pdf - this will be a bit offset by unnumbered or roman numbered frontmatter pages but you can probably quite reliably find the printed page number from that automatically by adding the appropriate number of pages. See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/457844/how-can-i-get-the-page-numbers-only-of-a-pattern-in-a-pdf-file-regardless-if-th for a usage example.